# How to make all browsers to render from the same css with same behavior and look

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a program or a framework which allows to build cross browser compatible html and css codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850363/is-there-a-program-or-a-framework-which-allows-to-build-cross-browser-compatible)

My problem is this, I have an application that have different behavior on IE, FF and Chrome. For example I have few buttons that looks different on IE and FF+Chrome browsers so how is possible to target all in order to run from the same css. In Chrome I have a problem with gradient for backgroun of all dropdown lists and many others. If anyone have a solution.
thank's.

Comment: There is not really a "one-size-fits-all" solution. Have a look at my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850363/is-there-a-program-or-a-framework-which-allows-to-build-cross-browser-compatible/8850500#8850500

Answer (score 0):

add to top of css file

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;

}
fieldset, img
{
    border: 0;
}
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var
{
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
ol, ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
caption, th
{
    text-align: left;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
q:before, q:after
{
    content: '';
}
abbr, acronym
{
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: this is meyers css reset right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try (likely in vain) to use conditional comments to set style information for each browser, or exploit known browser quirks, but the best and only way to get a uniform look across all browsers is to stick to W3C standards-compliant markup.

Aside from that, you can overcome graphics problems by using images instead of markup.